# Why is "necropolis" the answer to "Weird arachnid with venomous tail in the French cemetery"?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

This is a clue from the Irish Times cryptic crossword:

> Weird arachnid with venomous tail in the French cemetery

Answer: "necropolis". How was this arrived at?

Answer (score 17):

Hmm, an arachnid with venomous tail is a SCORPION, and "the" French is LE (French translation of "the"), and all that is anagrammed ("weird"), making NECROPOLIS (cemetery). This is an indirect anagram, and this is generally discouraged in cryptic clues since one unit can have many synonyms, and those synonyms most likely have more than one anagram, leading to many possible anagrams.

Comment: (Updated) See Chris Cudmore's and user39583's comments on Gareth's answer for better explanations, which takes into account the "in" in the clue surface. I think Chris's is better but regardless, as I've said, the indirect anagram is generally discouraged in the first place.

Comment: For what it's worth, "the scorpion" is "le scorpion" in French, so you don't need to just take the _le_.

Answer (score 10):

The definition is

> CEMETERY

and the wordplay

> is, naughtily, an *indirect anagram* (i.e., an anagram where the thing anagrammed involves some meaning-based wordplay), of SCORPION + LE.

Comment: I don't think it's 'scorpion' + 'le' but rather 'le scorpion' (otherwise the 'in' would be extraneous) (also for @oAlt)

Comment: Either that or "... with a venomous tail in". Both are pretty bad, but then so is the whole indirect-anagram thing.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, even with the "in" not being extraneous I think that's still poor, and as Gareth said the problem of the indirect anagram remains.

Comment: I think it's Weird ([Arachnid with a venomous tail] in [The French]) = CEMETARY
Which leads to LscorpionE*.    However, I'm of the opinion that if you're going to use an insertion to build indirect anagram fodder, then the fodder should be a word.

Comment: Is it usual in english crosswords to have anagrams without a hint of an anagram?

Comment: @FlorianF: There *is* a hint of an anagram: "weird".  Words related to disorder or strangeness usually signal anagrams in a cryptic.